# SQL/TSQL: Using PIVOT on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to solve two similar problems with PIVOT in SQL. I've got three tables:

- First one with columns: orderid, empid, orderdate;
- Second with columns: orderid, productid, unitprice
- Third one with columns: empid, firstname, lastname and so on (other information about workers)

Now, I need to use PIVOT to manage something like this:

```
empid firstname lastname 2006 2007 2008
1     aaa       bbb      1    55    77
1     aaa       bbb      2    58    79
2     xxx       ccc      4    59    82
.......................................
```

Where numbers in 2006, 2007, 2008 columns are orderids assigned for every year.

I've got something like this (query inside of `Pivott` works fine):

```
WITH Pivott AS
(
    SELECT
        so.empid, 
        YEAR(so.orderdate),
        so.orderid,
        hr.lastname,
        hr.firstname
    FROM 
        Sales.Orders so
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        HR.Employees hr ON so.empid = hr.empid
)
SELECT 
    YEAR(orderdate), [2006], [2007], [2008]
FROM 
    Pivott
PIVOT
    (SUM(orderid) FOR YEAR(orderdate) IN [2006], [2007], [2008]) AS PIV;
```

And the second problem:

I try to use PIVOT to manage something like this too:

```
empid firstname lastname 2006  2007  2008
1     aaa       bbb      453   34    77
2     vvv       kkk      345   89    123
3     xxx       ccc      453   12    82
.......................................
```

Where numbers in 2006, 2007, 2008 columns are the sum of all prices from orders performed by the worker (empid) in a given year.

I've got this:

```
WITH Pivott AS
(
    SELECT
        so.empid,
        YEAR(so.orderdate) AS YEAR,
        so.orderid AS ORDERS,
        hr.lastname,
        hr.firstname,
        s.unitprice AS SUMA
    FROM 
        Sales.Orders so
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        HR.Employees hr ON so.empid = hr.empid
    INNER JOIN
        Sales.OrderDetails s ON so.orderid = s.orderid
)
SELECT 
    YEAR(orderdate), [2006], [2007], [2008]
FROM 
    Pivott
PIVOT
    (SUM(unitprice) FOR YEAR(orderdate) IN ([2006], [2007], [2008])) AS PIV;
```

What I need to change to achieve my desired output?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: what is wrong with your query? why your initial result has emp id multiple times?

Comment: @radar Thanks for your reply! I have problems with syntax, for example now I've got error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '('.". So I'm doing something wrong inside of Pivott, but independently this queries works fine. In my first initial result I want to show all the numbers of orders (orderid) for given year and worker (for example someone performed four orders in 2006, so it should show their orderid by each year).

Comment: can you give few rows from both the tables to try the query

Comment: Can you post some sample data for each data along with the table structure?  Even better create a [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: @radar: I will paste them into question above.

Comment: Radar and @sqlfiddle - Thanks for your time! I just find out that the full base I'm learning from can be download here: http://tsql.solidq.com/books/tk70461/ (link Source Code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to apply the Pivot command against a CTE

try this;

```
;WITH pvtCTE AS
(SELECT so.empid,
YEAR(so.orderdate) AS SalesYEAR,
--so.orderid AS ORDERS, /** removed from grouping**/
hr.lastname,
hr.firstname,
SUM(ISNULL(s.unitprice,0.00)) as unitprice /** pre grouping adjusted per comment**/
FROM Sales.Orders so
left outer join HR.Employees hr on so.empid = hr.empid
inner join Sales.OrderDetails s on so.orderid = s.orderid
GROUP BY so.empid, YEAR(so,orderDate), hr.lastname, hr.firstname --added for aggregated CTE results
)

SELECT empid, firstname, lastname, [2006], [2007], [2008]
FROM (SELECT * FROM pvtCTE) p
PIVOT (
SUM(unitprice)
FOR SalesYEAR IN ([2006],[2007],[2008])
) as pvt;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for correct my ineffectual code. However, the result is only half satisfactory, I made a mistake somewhere. My output now looks like this: there is empid several times for each orderid, and there is a sum from all unitprices for each orderid by the year, first for 2006, next is NULL for 2007 and 2008, and then another row is for another orderid. Do you have a  idea what change to receive sum for all unitprices and all orders by years for each empid? Once again thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: Well if you're not concerned about the actual OrderID you can remove it from the select statement all together.  You're saying you just want it grouped based on Employee and year?

Comment: Wow. So simple answer, and I was so puzzled! It's what I need. Thank you very much, now I know how to deal with it. (I don't know who gave your answer "-1", I give you "+1").

Comment: You shouldn't need that additional `(select * from pvtCTE)` to get the result.

Comment: Technically you don't need the CTE at all and you could have nested the original select in the Parentheses.  The point was to delineate the two components.